# Random number creating

Tags: vba, excel

I got some help from one, and the code works perfectly fine.

What im looking for, is an explanation of the code, since my basic VBA-knowledge does not provide me with it.

Can someone explain what happens from "Function" and down?

```
Sub Opgave8()

For i = 2 To 18288
    If Left(Worksheets("arab").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
        Worksheets("arab").Cells(i, 3) = "18" & UniqueRandDigits(5)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
Function UniqueRandDigits(x As Long) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim s As String
Do
n = Int(Rnd() * 10)
If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then
s = s & n
i = i + 1
End If
Loop Until i = x + 1

UniqueRandDigits = s
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

`n = Int(Rnd()*10)` returns a value between 0 and 9, since `Rnd` returns a value between 0 and 1 and `Int` converts it to an integer, aka, a natural number.

Then `If InStr(s, n) = 0` checks if the random number is already in your result: if not, it adds it using the string concatenation operator `&`.

This process loops (`do`) `until i = x + 1` where `x` is your input argument, so you get a string of length `x`. Then the first part just fills rows with these random strings.

N.B. : I explained using the logical order of the code. Your friend function `UniqRandDigits` is defined after the "business logic", but it's the root of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I dont understand what you mean about After the "Business logic"?

Comment: @Simon "business logic" is the part of your code, which uses generic functions like `UniqRandDigits` to do specific functions, in your case, filling rows based on a certain condition. But it's not important, it was just to separate the two parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The code loops from row 2 to 18288 in Worksheet "arab". If first 6 characters in 12th column are "262015", then in 3rd column macro will fill cell with value "18" followed by result of function `UniqueRandDigits(5)` which generates 5 unique digits (0-9).

About the `UniqueRandDigits` function, the most important is that `Rnd()` returns a value lesser than 1 but greater than or equal to zero.

`Int` returns integer value, so `Int(Rnd() * 10)` will generate a random integer number from 0 to 9.

`If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then` makes sure than generated integer value doesn't exist in already generated digits of this number, because as the function name says, they must be unique.